# if the original JS has many functions, how dart to initiate them?

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

after several rounds of research, I found there is no clear answer about the situation like below:

I have a js file called 'AAA.js', and there is simple code in side like this:

```
    var AAA = {
       listenForMenuLayer: function () {
           console.log("menu initiated");
           $('.nav-menu').on('click', function() { console.log("menu clicked")});
       }

         init: function(){
            this.listenForMenuLayer();
         }
    };
```

And in the dart, I wrote like below (using 'dart:js'):

```
js.context['AAA'].callMethod('init');
```

Then, when I run it, everything looks fine, the **"menu initiated" shows properly**, which means the 'listenForMenuLayer' is initiated, but when click on the '.nav-menu', **there is nothing happened**. (I check many times, there is no spelling error or else)

My question is: Can Dart accept this kind of initiating of external JS event? or we should re-write those JS events at all, please advise, many thanks.

**Updates:**
I found that if we write the js code like above, the jquery will not be initiated properly, which means all the features begin with '$' will not be functional.

Comment: From my knowledge, this should work, did you try to log the return of `$('.nav-menu')` to see if it exist ? and did you try with package:js https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js, they recommend to use this package instead of dart:js

Comment: @HadrienLejard hi, thanks for replying, I am going to try it.

Comment: @Charles to your last update. That doesn't seem to be related to Dart. Perhaps jquery is not yet initialized or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

guys, I update it to using 'package:js/js.dart';

```
@JS('AAA.init')
external void aInit();
```

then some where, just simply call after including:

```
aInit();
```